# Как правильно спроектировать?

Tags: ооп, проектирование, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования

Помогите разобраться... А то у меня опыта не хватает, как лучше спроектировать данное приложение.

Пример задачи: транслитерация алфавита
есть буквы например русского языка абвгд... (они могут быть как строчными так и заглавными абвгд...АБВГД). Конвертируем в английские буквы строчные в строчные, заглавные в заглавные.

С точки зрения архитектуры объектом будет являться буква или алфавит?

Возможные варианты расширения:

1. смена алфавита (языка)
2. конвертирование строчных в заглавные, а заглавные в строчные.

Есть предположение рассматривать алфавит как абстрактную фабрику и расширять его другими языками.

Comment: > с точки зрения архитектуры объектом будет являться буква или алфавит?

и то, и другое, если пишете на Java к примеру. Программисты на perl тихо давятся от смеха - у них есть регулярки и `tr///`.

Сложности начнутся только тогда, когда двум буквам исходной строки может соответствовать одна-две результата и это не очевидно (проявляется при обратной транслитерации с латиницы на кириллицу). 

Правильная проектировка - нужна функция, которая загрузит массив букв и их соответствий. Вторая функция пройдется циклом и сделает подмену.

Comment: да пишу на java, получается буква суперкласс алфавита?
а как быть с заглавными и строчными?
если добавится новый алфавит новый массив?

Comment: буква - суперкласс алфавита? м, навряд ли. Алфавит - это массив/упорядоченная коллекция букв.

> если добавится новый алфавит

просто добавится один файл с данными.

Comment: а что с классами, кто кого наследовать будет и какими свойствами обладать?

Comment: а что, без наследования задачу уже решить нельзя? как по мне, то в этой задаче одного класса хватит с головой. Ну максимум ещё один для обработки хитрых ситуаций (например, правильно транслитировать shch -> щ).

Comment: можно... можно все в одном классе написать и даже в одном методе. Только не хочется такой лапши, хочется красиво...

Comment: Вы уверены, что 10 классов красивее чем один?

Comment: >Только не хочется такой лапши, хочется красиво...
======
>вопрос задан с целью разобраться как сделать класиво
======
>хочется понять как сделать красиво
======
>так у меня уже работает, хочется сделать красиво

оставлю это без комментариев

Comment: если все логически правильно построено, то думаю да.

Answer (score 11):

В данном случаем Вы микроскопом гвозди забивать собрались. Из Ваших речей понятно что Вы начитались паттернов банды четырёх. И видимо не дочитали до конца, где написано что не стоит на банальные задачи городить мегаконструкции.

Comment: да начитался, но на счет гвоздей и микроскопа не согласен, простая реализация у меня уже есть, но я вижу ее недостатки, при расширении прийдется городить огород.

Comment: помимо KISS стоит упомянуть и про схожий с ним [YAGNI][1], которому ТС также противоречит

[1]:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it

Comment: еще раз у меня есть реализация функциональным кодом, вопрос задан с целью разобраться как сделать класиво. Я понимаю что парадигм проектирования масса, можно все построить на интерфейсах, можно в рамках парадигм ООП, можно использовать патерны, хочется понять как сделать красиво.

Comment: @Nub, конечно, понятие *красиво* субъективно. 

Но поверьте, многим, то что Вы пытаетесь изобразить, кажется безобразным.

Comment: то есть вы считаете что использование ооп и паттернов это зло? нет я конечно помню пост на хабре по поводу выпекания булок... но все же хотелость бы попробовать сделать красивую архитектуру, накодить, а потом посмотреть.

Comment: может покажете свой текущий код (оформите отдельным вопросом), а там будет видно, что переделывать.

Comment: @Nub, все хорошо к месту и в меру. Не забывайте:


    "автомобиль - это страшное оружие в руках молодого бойца"

(из армейского юмора).

Comment: @Nub, cкажите конкретно, какие недостатки есть у простой реализации? Думаю, не только я вижу решение исходной задачи одним методом из 5-ти строк и классика. Да и то класс нужен только чтобы наглядным способом заполнить массив соответствий.

Answer (score 5):

- Думать о возможности расширения при написании какого-либо кода — это известный pitfall. Вы тратите время, занимаясь фреймворкостроганием и закладывая возможность масштабирования, которая, скорее всего, вам никогда не понадобится (1), требует ресурсов на реализацию и поддержание уже написанных тестов (2), не решает никакую практическую user story (3).

> Поставьте себе задачу, напишите постановку задачи и решите ее (и только ее), следуя [принципу Keep It Simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Когда потребуется что-то расширить — тогда и подумаете об этом.

- Ваша задача — это реальная production задача или же ваш учебный эксперимент*?

> - Если это настоящая задача и у вас есть решение, которое: консистентно с другим уже существующим кодом (1), проходит все unit- и integration-тесты (2), не содержит спорных или неочевидных моментов (3), корректно обрабатывает хитроумные edge-кейсы вроде входных данных в виде пачки суррогатных пар в UTF-16 (4), то **вы просто теряете время** и рискуете заработать ООП головного мозга.
> - Если это учебный эксперимент, то вы тоже делаете неправильно. Вам нужно перебрать все различные способы реализовать эту же задачу, а не пытаться "сделать красиво".
> - Возьмите 6 разных языков, 6 разных тестовых фреймворков к ним, сделайте универсальную пачку входных тест-кейсов, которую можно использовать для каждого из этих фреймворков и напишите хорошо на каждом из этих языков. Сделайте так, чтобы ваш код по своему flow'у и look-and-feel'у не отличался от "best code examples" для каждого из этих языков.
> - Дальше — больше. Сделайте одно из решений многопоточным. Разделите вашу задачу на server- и client-side, и сделайте 2-3 приклада на разных технологиях для вашего сервера. Решите эту же задачу, но следуя принципам TDD / BDD, а потом сравните, что получилось. Возьмите одно из решений этой задачи и отправьте его на review человеку, который работает с этим языком.

Answer (score 4):

Взорвал мозг. Зачем такие сложности? Можно сделать хеш(ассоциативный массив), где ключи это русские буквы, а значения английские. В зависимости от языка реализация немного будет отличаться, но по мне тут всё просто и городить паттерны немного перебор.

Comment: ваше мнение совпало с первым коментатором, можно сделать и у меня подобным образом реализовано, но если мы захотим добавить новый алфавит, конвертацию заглавных в строчные? а строчные в заглавные? что нам прийдется делать? правильно переписывать массив (предполагается что под буквами другие объекты, которые нельзя сделать lowcase)

Comment: Для алфавитов, в которых lowercase не предусмотрен явно, делаем свой lowercase на тех же хэш-таблицах. Добавлние любого нового языка сведётся к написанию схем перевода upper -> lower (и, возможно, обратно) и перевода с языка на английский и обратно. Никаких паттернов, только хэш-таблицы.

Comment: так у меня уже работает, хочется сделать красиво

Answer (score 0):

Не вдаваясь в умничание все таки замечу, что:

1. Объектом является то над чем производится какое-то действо: стул-сидеть, книга-читать, машина-ехать и проч.
2. Так что в данном случае объектом является алфавит

**P.S.** Мне кажется что алфавит в данном контексте вполне тянет на Java класс [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). Конечно, создание кастомного локаля дело довольно трудоемкое, но почему нет? Гугль с первой же страницы [находит пример](http://klaus.e175.net/java-locale-sh) создания кастомной сербо-хорватской локали. Не понимаю почему бы транслиту не выступить некой извращенной формой локали?

Comment: Проще говоря, объект - это сущность в программировании, которая обладает состоянием.