# Архитектура простейшего приложеня

Tags: android

Пишу приложение чисто для себя. Приложение по йоге, где все упражнения находятся в определённой последовательности (последовательность известна изначально).
1) После прохождения каждого упражнения будет автоматически отображаться следующее упражнение.
2) Конец каждого упражнения будет определён с помощью таймера. 
3) Каждое упражнение состоит из картинки (или несколько картинок), текста, кнопки старт.

У меня в голове возникает простейшая архитектура: один главный класс, загружающий последовательность упражнений и класс "Упражнение". Может можно сделать архитектуру интереснее? кто бы что добавил? И как хранить лучше заранее известные данные - просто в ресурсах?

Comment: два основных класса - очень хорошо. Данные - если их не много - можно и в ресурсах. Если побольше - то лучше отдельно загрузить. Если Вы будете делать картинки заданий, то наверно под разные разрешение будет свой комплект? Так вот, не идите на поводу у других - сделайте базовый набор (пусть и в относительно плохом качестве) в ресурсах, а пользователю в настройках (и при первом запуске) дайте возможность выкачать ресурсы под его параметры.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Не усложняйте!](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF)) Не стоит делать архитектуру только ради архитектуры. Пусть ваше приложение сначала заработает с простой архитектурой, тогда вам станут видны её недостатки в контексте авшей задачи. Тогда и подумаете, что стоит изменить, чтобы ваше приложение было более гибким и расширяемым (если это понадобится). Вчера был [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/251647/%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%BF-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), в котором человек пытался вводить ООП в задачу, в котором оно не нужно. Не уподобляйтесь ему.

Comment: ок :)))))))

Comment: Согласен с тем что усложнять не стоит, но главное идти на разумные компромиссы. Часто бывает что упрощая, как им кажется, а-ля программисты все в одной активити пишут, а еще веселее если все в методе onCreate()